# Returning Empty table in SQL Server after execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I have a problem with my stored procedure. I'm a bit confused about that because the stored procedure how I defined before it was working fine, but now it doesn't work.

Here the T-SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMonthMaxVal] 
    @from datetime,
    @to datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ds22.*
    FROM (SELECT 
                MAX(DAY(ds.datum)) AS TagMax,
                MONTH(ds.datum) AS MonatMax,
                YEAR(ds.datum) AS JahrMax,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(ds.datum), 120) AS DatumMax
          FROM QR_DS022s ds
          WHERE ds.datum >= @from AND ds.datum <= @to
          GROUP BY MONTH(ds.datum), YEAR(ds.datum)) maxDate INNER JOIN QR_DS022s ds22 ON maxDate.DatumMax = ds22.datum
    ORDER BY ds22.datum
END
```

In the SQL Server 2008 R2 this stored procedure was working fine. In SQL Server 2014 it doesn't work. What's wrong?

EDIT:

When I'm executing the SP with the code:

```
EXECUTE ETF_DB.dbo.getMonthMaxVal @from='2014-01-01', @to='2014-04-01'
```

I'm getting an empty table with empty columns.

When I'm doing this:

```
EXECUTE ETF_DB.dbo.getMonthMaxVal @from='2014-01-01', @to='2014-04-02'
```

I'm getting an error message:

> When converting a varchar data type to a datetime data type, the value
>   is out of range.

Comment: Define working/not working. provide more backgroud. share relevant schema. Generally, read [ask]

Comment: @Amit I guess you can read my stored procedure. Well, if you understand the code above, you can see that I want to return all columns from the table `ds22` but only the last day from the month. Therefore I defined a sub select. When I execute the SP with `EXECUTE ETF_DB.dbo.getMonthMaxVal @from='2014-01-01', @to='2014-04-01'` then I'm getting an empty table with empty columns.

Comment: try using DATE datatype instead of DATETIME and VARCHAR to handle dates only values, without time component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't see any data, and table structure, i'd remove the VARCHAR reference and use DATE across the board:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMonthMaxVal] 
    @from   DATE,
    @to     DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ds22.*
    FROM (  SELECT 
                    MAX(DAY(ds.datum)) AS TagMax,
                    MONTH(ds.datum) AS MonatMax,
                    YEAR(ds.datum) AS JahrMax,
                    CONVERT(DATE, MAX(ds.datum)) AS DatumMax
              FROM QR_DS022s ds
              WHERE ds.datum >= @from AND ds.datum <= @to
              GROUP BY MONTH(ds.datum), YEAR(ds.datum)) maxDate 
          INNER JOIN QR_DS022s ds22 
            ON maxDate.DatumMax = CONVERT(DATE, ds22.datum)
    ORDER BY ds22.datum
END
```

Let me know if that fixes your problem.